# Working with predefined arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I am creating an own generic collection class in C#, and Im working on an array that stores a list that should have an predefined length (It should start with a length of 2). Now I have no idea on how to make it start with a length of 2. For example, if I create an array:

private int[] numbers = new int[20];

How do I predefined it length so it starts with a length of 2?

Comment: err.. private int[] numbers = new int[2];

Comment: rivate int[] numbers = new int[2];

Comment: Remove the `0` from your example

Comment: Given the collections available, do you really want to create your own "own generic collection class in C#"? Beacuse if you stuck on this, then you'd better write lots of unit tests....

Comment: You mean, that numbers.Length return 20 and you want it to return the actual inserted elements? If so, you need to introduce another field numbersLength = 2. Then after adding new element to numbers do numbersLength++.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason to do that. However you can create arrays with length 2 ->

`private int[] numbers = new int[2];`.

Also, you can use `List<T>` to do just that and forget about memory management? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use  one of the build in classes. They will hadle everything for you avoiding errors.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        numbers.Add(123);
        int i = numbers[0];
        int[] asArray = numbers.ToArray();
```